# Type mismatch, expected ((String,List[Product with Serializable])) => Boolean, actual ((String,List[Product with Serializable])) => Any

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This are two sample entries from my RDD (`RDD[(String, Map[String,List[Product wuth Serializable]])]`):

```
(600,Map(current_data -> List((600,111,1,1), (615,111,1,5)), additional_data -> List((3,120,1,1,3370,f,0,268.78)))
(601,Map(current_data -> List((600,111,1,1), (615,111,1,5)), additional_data -> List((3,110,1,0,3370,f,0,268.78)))
```

I want to filter out entries that in the sub-list accessed by "additional_data" contain 0 in the 3rd field.

For instance, in the above example the list `List((3,110,1,0,3370,f,0,268.78))` contains `0` in the 3rd field. Therefore the whole entry should be deleted and result is:

```
(600,Map(current_data -> List((600,111,1,1), (615,111,1,5)), additional_data -> List((3,120,1,1,3370,f,0,268.78)))
```

This is my current code, which does not compile because of the error `Type mismatch, expected ((String,List[Product with Serializable])) => Boolean, actual ((String,List[Product with Serializable])) => Any`.

```
  val result = myRDD.filter({
    case (id, list) => !list.exists({
      t => (t.get("additional_data").map(_._3) == 0)
    })
  })
```

UPDATE:

My final attempt is the foolowing. It can be compiled, but does not solve the task for some reason. I checked that `l.productElement(3)` is really equal to `0` for some entries, but these entries are not deleted...:

```
val result = myRDD.filter{ 
  case (id, hmap) => !hmap.get("member_data").exists({ 
    t => (t.exists({ l => l.productElement(3).equals(0)}))
  }) 
}
```

Comment: Which expression produce error?

Comment: @talex: `get` is marked in red. So, it looks like I am not accessing `Map`.

Comment: What is type of `t`?

Comment: @talex: It's `(String,List[Product with Serializable])`. So, I don't know how to access `Map`.

Comment: @talex: This is the type of RDD: `RDD[(String, Map[String,List[Product wuth Serializable]])]`

Answer (score 0):

I belive you should change you code this way

```
val result = myRDD.filter{
    case (id, map) => !map.get("additional_data").map(_._3).exists(_==0)
}
```

Comment: You could've undeleted your other answer

Comment: If I change the code this way `case (id, map) => !map.get("member_data").exists(_==0)`, then it can be compiled, but how can I specify the 3rd element in the List? I tried to improve the code this, way (it does not work so far): `val result = myRDD.filter{
        case (id, map) => !map.get("additional_data").exists({
          t => (t.map({l => l.productElement(3) ==0}))})
      }`

Comment: Finally I came out with this code, which compiles, but does not do anything: `val result = myRDD.filter{
        case (id, hmap) => !hmap.get("member_data").exists({
          t => (t.exists({
            l => l.productElement(3).equals(3)
          }))})
      }`

Comment: Try replace `map(_._3)` with `map(_.productElement(3))`